# function declaration in core.c

Tags: c, function

I found this declaration in `kernel/sched/core.c` and I do not understand what does this specify.

`static void __sched __schedule(void)`

Any help appreciated.

[EDIT] kernel version 3.5.4

Comment: Ahh, wow, I was actually checking in an *older* version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`__sched` is actually a macro defined as `__attribute__((__section__(".sched.text")))` in `include/linux/sched.h`. This attribute is picked up by the [GCC compiler](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html):

> Normally, the compiler places the objects it generates in sections
>   like data and bss. Sometimes, however, you need additional sections,
>   or you need certain particular variables to appear in special
>   sections, for example to map to special hardware. The section
>   attribute specifies that a variable (or function) lives in a
>   particular section.

Comment: but what does this evaluates to. I mean in function declaration after function return type the function name should be there

Comment: and it would be great if you can tell how to interpret this or give some pointers where I can pick this up from. I am new to such stuff

Comment: You can find the documentation of the `__attribute__` syntax here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html

Comment: I am sorry but your recent edit just bounced over the head. I think I need to do a bit of homework. Can you suggest a good read about it.

Comment: The link that @Mark gave describes how the attribute syntax is used in GCC and the link I gave in my post should show specifically what that particular attribute achieves.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam 'the function name should be there' -- The function name is `__schedule`. It's hard to see what you're not getting about this.

Comment: @JimBalter what I was confused about is macro `__sched` but it is clear now

Comment: @MikeKwan Well I went through both of them..:) thanks for all help.